# Unregister all event in WebSocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

How can stop listening to all events in websocket.

```
const WebSocketClient = require('ws');
const ws = new WebSocketClient('wss://example.com');
ws.on('message', doFunction());

function doFunction() {
  if (condition) {
    //do some stuff
    //stop listening to event without closing the websocket connection
  }
}
```

ws.close() or ws.terminate() will close the connection, I don't want to close the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `WebSocketClient` extends `EventEmitter`, you can surely call `ws.removeAllListeners()`.

[EventEmitter.removeAllListeners docs](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removealllisteners_eventname) and [ws#WebSocket docs](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/HEAD/doc/ws.md#class-websocket) should help anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to remove the event listeners manually. They remain active on the element until they are destroyed (or removed by the browser).